# No protocol specified

Tags: linux, debian

I can't run any of the graphical applications from root terminal.

```
No protocol specified
xhost:  Unable to open display ":0.0"
```

Any idea what to look for?

Comment: A very quick Googling of that issue reveals many possible solutions.

Comment: I'm here after 2 hours of googling. I couldn't execute the xhost command either to try some possible solutions recommended. Same error msg.